# How to make the [...] in the get_the_excerpt() as a hyperlink

Tags: wordpress

I want to make the [...] displayed in posts page as hyperlink to that particular posts. I get to know that this is from get_the_excerpt().

How can this be achieved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27933/display-links-in-excerpts
check it this might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy this function to your functions.php

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
       global $post;
    return '<span class="readmore"><a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> Read more..</a></span>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```